# MongoDB WildCard query taking too much time using Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

- MongoDB v4.0.2
- Grails 3.3.5

I've more than 20 Millions of records stored in a collection. I'm trying to wildcard search in that collection like as follows...

```
def personList = Person.collection.find(['vehicleNumber': ['$regex':/.*GJ18AD.*/] ]).sort(["datetime":-1])
```

Index on Person Collection

```
db.person.getIndexes()
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "vehicleNumber" : 1
    },
    "name" : "vehicleNumber_1",
    "ns" : "analytics.person",
    "weights" : {
        "numberPlate" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

Is there any other way for the wildcard search?

Comment: how much time does it take w/o Grails?

Comment: Not getting results even after 30 Minutes.

Comment: what if you run the same query in mongo console?

Comment: within a minute 
(Query looks like **db.person.find({'vehicleNumber': {'$regex': /.*GJ18AD.*/}}**)

Comment: then you should run exactly the same query in GORM: `Person.collection.find( vehicleNumber:[ $regex:/.*GJ18AD.*/ ] ).sort( datetime:-1 )`

Comment: Tried but not working (No results found).

Comment: If I understand correctly then your problem is: "Your query works in a Mongo console as well as in Mongo client(like robo3t) but not with the grails code." Right?

Comment: @MananShah: To be exact grails take double then Mongo console. If console result optimised then automatically grails results been optimised.
Note that if I going to search like /.*G.*J.*/ it will give me results in less then 2 seconds. But search string like /.*G.*J.*4.*5.*E.*/  taking more than a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no changes required in the indexing. But the minor change in the filter Object which I'm passing to the collection.

Previously, I was using following filter object syntax:

```
 def personList = Person.collection.find(['vehicleNumber': ['$regex':/.*GJ18AD.*/] ]).sort(['datetime':-1])
```

Then I've change only the regex in the above syntax:

```
def personList = Person.collection.find(['vehicleNumber': ['$regex':'.*GJ18AD.*'] ]).sort(['datetime':-1])
```

It's works for me in the MongoDB version 4.2.1.